# Zoom In graphael

Tags: javascript

Estou a utilizar o `graphael` para criar gráfico de linhas. Quero criar um zoom, ou seja, tenho o array e quero os valores entre -20 e 30. Como os meus valores estão entre 20 e 25 no eixo dos y, quero adicionar entre -20 e 30 e recalcular para ficarem bem posicionados entre os novos valores. Não sei se tem e ver com o gutter utilizado na biblioteca.

Exemplo jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aNJxf/23/

Comment: Consegui chegar ao que queria, apenas tenho um pequeno problema no eixo dos x. exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/vpGyL/1431/